# Structured data logo is not visible in Google Search

Tags: magento2, google-search, google-rich-snippets

We have one website on Magento where we added the structure data for the website logo and contact. Here is the code:

```json
{
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "Organization",
"name" : "Website Name",
"url" : "https://www.website.com/",
"logo" : "https://www.website.com/pub/media/logo/stores/1/logo_1.png",
"contactPoint" : [{
"@type" : "ContactPoint",
"telephone" : "+1-111-222-333",
"email" : "in...@website.com",
"contactType" : "customer service"
}],
"sameAs" : [
"https://www.facebook.com/website-World-LLC-258456985/",
"https://twitter.com/Website",
"https://www.linkedin.com/company/website-url-llc",
"https://plus.google.com/+websiteUrl/about",
"http://www.pinterest.com/website/"
]
}
```

We have validated the code onto the [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) and there is no issue on that.

We added this code since before 6 months but still, logo, contact and the social icon does not show in the Google Search: https://prnt.sc/jlnvrs

Also, we added the Google schema for the product reviews on the website and validated on the structured data testing tool and there is no issue on that but still reviews are not displayed on Google search result.

Can anyone have an idea, why the business logo is not displayed on this?

Comment: Maybe you can clarify your question:
* Specify the size of the image used for the logo
* Is this image indexable?

Comment: Here is the website logo: https://www.compressorworld.com/pub/media/logo/stores/1/cwlogo_1.png  Logo size is 239x36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **[Google guide to Logo](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo)**:

> The image must be 112x112px, at minimum.

Your logo that you specified does not have the required sizes. Create a match for this requirement by Google.

Also in this guide says:

> The image URL must be crawlable and indexable.

However, your logo does not match this: with the operator **[site](https://www.google.se/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.compressorworld.com%2Fpub%2Fmedia%2Flogo%2Fstores%2F1%2Fcwlogo_1.png)** and with the operator **[info](https://www.google.se/search?q=info%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.compressorworld.com%2Fpub%2Fmedia%2Flogo%2Fstores%2F1%2Fcwlogo_1.png)**.

Create also a match with this requirement.

Comment: We updated the google schema and changed the logo to meet the requirement: https://www.compressorworld.com/logo.png Now what is the next step?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. My image is above 112x112 px. I'm using a jpg.
What do they mean with crawlable and indexable? Does is mean that the logo must be shown somewhere on the website? Or is it ok if I'm using a variation of the company logo, and the link is ok too.

Comment: @ Jonas Merhej. This means that the logo must be available for Googlebot and not blocked in the robots.